# Lazarus get sql result to dbedit

Tags: delphi-7, lazarus

I need to get result of select statement in Lazarus and assign this result to edit.text.

**CODE**:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  Q: TSQLQuery;
  d: string;
begin
  //Q := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);

  with OracleConnection1 do
  begin
    Connected := true;
    SQLTransaction1.Active:= True;

    DataSource1.Enabled:=true;
    DataSource1.DataSet := Q;
  end;
  if OracleConnection1.Connected then

   Q.SQL.Text := 'SELECT description FROM part where part= "00000" ';
   Q.Active:=true;
   Q.ExecSQL;
   d := datasource1.DataSet;
   //DBText1.ExecuteAction();
   dbedit1.Text:= q.DataSource.DataSet.Fields.;

   Edit1.Text:= Q.SQL.Text;
   showmessage('CONNECTED');
   sql.Active:=true;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got quite a few errors in your code. You should probably find a tutorial on Delphi somewhere (which is very similar to Lazarus and FreePascal).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Qry: TSQLQuery;
begin
  Qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  with OracleConnection1 do
  begin
    Connected := true;
    SQLTransaction1.Active:= True;
    DataSource1.Enabled:=true;
    DataSource1.DataSet := Q;
  end;
  if OracleConnection1.Connected then
  begin
   showmessage('CONNECTED');
   Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT description FROM part where part= "00000" ';
   Qry.Open; 

   Edit1.Text:= Qry.FieldByName('description').AsString;
end;
```